# How to run Matlab batch script and save the results

Tags: bash, matlab, sh

```
#!/bin/bash
###########################
#
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12
#PBS -l walltime=00:30:00
```

XXXXXXXXXx and below is my script details about running matlab
I want to save the results from the trial.m however it does not work.

```
export JOBID=`echo "${PBS_JOBID}" | cut -d'.' -f1`
cd ${PBS_O_WORKDIR}
module load matlab/R2017b
matlab
trial.m
```

My script name: trial.m
How to save the results from trial.m to my environment?
In my trial.m matlab file, I have the following codes to display my results, does this work? betas and values are two vector of numbers

```
disp(betas); 
disp(values);
save('parameters.mat','betas','values');
```

In addition, trial.m needs to call external functions that I saved in the same file, can it call automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoke MATLAB and execute `trial.m` via the following command:

```
matlab -r trial -logfile logfile.log -nodisplay -nosplash
```

Make sure `trial.m` exits MATLAB when it finishes, to continue executing any post-processing steps. You should also suppress the MATLAB GUI and Splash screens since the script is running non-interactively. Also make sure that `trial.m` forces MATLAB to exit by using the `exit` command.

Save the results of `trial.m` to the environment by calling the `save` function to create a .MAT file. 
NOTE: To access the file using other software, save in CSV format by calling [csvwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html).

```
csvwrite('betas.csv',betas);
csvwrite('values.csv',values);
```

#### MATLAB Alternative to Bash

Alternatively you could use MATLAB's [parrallel computing toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/program-independent-jobs-for-a-supported-scheduler.html) to submit the job. In this case you no longer need the bash script. However, you would need to modify your MATLAB files to handle the job submission to the cluster ([here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/program-independent-jobs-for-a-supported-scheduler.html)).

Comment: do I need to add commands in matlab.m file indicating that I am running batch job through the cluster? I saw that R has similar function in script.pbs file R CMD BATCH indicating running batch job

Comment: @vera_kkk, see my edits. I hope they answer your question about what is needed to be done to prepare your job for submission.